# Uniform Cost Search and its Time/Space Complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, search, graph, graph-algorithm

As part of a programming assignment, I have written a function `ucs(G,v)` in Python 3 which searches a digraph `G` which has weighted edges. Three nodes in `G` are randomly selected as *goal nodes*, and the task of this function is to apply uniform cost search (i.e. cheapest first search) to find the cheapest path from a given node `v` to one of the goal nodes.

I have two questions:

- Is the implementation correct? I suspect that redundant checks are being made when multiple paths to the same node are pushed onto the priority queue.
- How can I go about determining the time and space complexities in terms of |V| and |E|?

I appreciate any suggestions, especially with the second question. I cannot find the complexity of UCS anywhere online in terms of |V| and |E|.

Here is my implementation:

```python
def ucs(G, v):
    visited = set()                  # set of visited nodes
    q = queue.PriorityQueue()        # paths are tuples with cumulative cost
    q.put((0, [v]))                  # add the starting node, zero cost   

    while not q.empty():             # while the queue is nonempty
        current_path_priority, current_path = q.get()  # get top item
        current_node = current_path[-1]    # current_node is the node at the end  
        visited.add(current_node)          # mark it as visited

        if current_node.is_goal:           # if the current node is a goal
            return current_path            # return it

        else:
            for edge in current_node.out_edges: # otherwise, for each neighbour
                child = edge.to()             # (avoid calling .to() in future)

                if child not in visited:                # if it is not visited 
                    new_cost = current_path_priority + edge.weight  
                    q.put((new_cost, current_path + [child]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question: The code seems fine to me.

Regarding your second question:

*Uniform Cost Search* does not use a heuristic function (it is a brute force search). If all edges have a positive cost, UCS will eventually reach a goal of finite cost. In such case, if a finite path to a goal node exists, UCS returns the optimal path.

#### Time Complexity

[image: time complexity] - where *e* is the minimum cost per edge, *b* is the branching factor and *c* is the *Cost*.
Thus, to discover all nodes up to cost *c*, a correct algorithm *must* generate all nodes up to depth `c/e`. Otherwise, there could be a better (cheaper) solution, that was not found.
So, the algorithm worst case time complexity is [image: time complexity] (because you branch out by a factor of `b` on each level)

#### Space Complexity

Each generated node is stored in either the *Open List* or the *Close List*, thus time and space complexity are actually same. Which means that space complexity is also [image: space complexity].

#### Limitation

UCS is considered *memory limited* since the memory requirement is exponential.